# How do I delete a clone game object instead of the original gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am Making a game where I need rooms to be generated when the door to the next is opened and then once 3 rooms have been generated the room 3 rooms back needs to be deleted, here is my code for deleting the third back room:

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;

  public class RoomDeGenarator : MonoBehaviour
  {
  private float RoomsOpened = 0;
  public void DoorCount(){
     RoomsOpened ++;
     if(RoomsOpened > 3.0f){
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

}

every time a door is opened to the next room it generate the next, so every time a new room is generated it adds 1 to "RoomsOpened", the code works fine its just that when it deletes the game object it deletes the original one instead of the clone

so, how do I delete the clone instead of the original gameobject?

Answer (score 1):

Keep your room in a list, add them on creation. When your list count is 4, destroy first item

```
List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();

void OnRoomCreate()
{
      Room newRoom = CreateRoom();
      rooms.Add(newRoom);
      if (rooms.Count >= 4)
      {
          Destroy(list[0]);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate object by giving it variable name.

`GameObject room = Instantiate(roomPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);`

Then you can say
`Destroy(room);`